# call fragment inside the AppWidgetProvider class

Tags: android, fragment

I am creating widgets in android.We call the activity through the intents in AppWidgetProvider class.
But what is the way for calling Fragments inside AppWidgetProvider class?

Answer (score 0):

> But what is the way for calling Fragments inside AppWidgetProvider class?

Fragments are for use by activities, not app widgets.

Comment: But when user click on textview on appwidget ,i want to display data into fragment

Comment: @kirankk: You are welcome to have the app widget start an activity in response to the click. Or, you are welcome to update the `RemoteViews` for the app widget itself in response to the click. You cannot use a fragment inside of an app widget.

Comment: But From wedget I need to call a fragment of my main app. And how to do that>>??